# How am I allowed to locally install bash version 4.3 on a system where there's bash version 4.1

Tags: linux, bash, installation

On a Linux target system, where I'm not the administrator, I need to upgrade the bash from 4.1 to 4.3 but for security reason isn't possible to do that.

I tried to copy bash 4.3 on the system in a local directory with the appropriate libc library, but (obviously) the target system lacks the presence of other libraries that version 4.3 need and anyway the copied libraries are not seen by the new bash I've copied.

Do you have suggestions to locally install bash?

My system is `Linux HOSTNAME 4.4.0-141-generic #167-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 10:40:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

**The target system where I've the issue is `Linux HOSTNAME 2.6.32-431.53.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Mar 9 11:46:18 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`**

Comment: What distro do you use?

Comment: @uzsolt. I've reported systems specification in the question.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access